# Sum the total of a column in another worksheet

Tags: excel, reference, worksheet

I am looking for a nice formula that will sum the total of a column in a worksheet indirectly.

I have Worksheet 1 with two columns

```
A             B
Worksheet1
Worksheet2
workSheet3
```

I need to fill B with the value of the SUm of column C in the corresponding worksheets in column A

So if the sum of Column C in Worksheet1 was 15, I would expect 15 to show in Column B next to worksheet1.

My attempt so far has failed using `=SUM(INDIRECT(A54,TRUE)!C:C)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that won't work because `INDIRECT` takes only one parameter. Try this instead:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'"&A54&"'!C:C"))
```

The `&` concatenates the value of A54 with that of `!C:C`, which, for the first worksheet is: `Worksheet1!C:C` which is the syntax for referencing from other sheets. :)

EDIT: I added single quotes because if you have, for example a worksheet name with a space (e.g. `Worksheet 1`, the function will give you an error). The single quote will regroup the whole worksheet name together and prevents excel from getting confused.

Comment: +1, and as a side note, may want to surround A54 with single quotes just in case a worksheet name has spaces in it